# Can't rdp into new ( or old ) Azure VM

Tags: virtual-machines, rdp, azure, credentials

I have an Azure account with a VM on it.  I haven't used it in about 8 months.  I tried to connect today but it wont take my creds.  Now I'm not entirely sure that I have my password correct, pretty sure but not entirely.  So I created a new VM and set the password.  Clicked the Connect button on the portal window, tried to connect and was rejected using the password I know to be correct.  I have disabled my local machine firewall and antivirus.

Comment: Sounds like you should contact Azure support.

Answer (score 0):

Crap, so the rdp file that downloads sets the user name to administrator.  Google searches reinforced the idea that that was the default and perhaps only username.  So I just assumed that was it.  However,  it turns out that I had my own un.

I further hypothesize that the un stays constant for all vms or because I specified the same dns server when creating the new vm the un carried over.

Clearly user error,  but I still want to blame microsoft somehow.